# Webpage dropdown menu on IE and Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, dropdown, polylang

**This is a very basic dropdown and IE question**

I have a dropdown menu on webpage. Main menu is built with WP shapely theme and Polylang plugin (translation).  `Chrome` and other browsers except `IE` and `Edge` are displaying dropdown `on hover` and also `on click`.
I need it to dropdown on all browsers available on click at least.

Here is my `HTML` and `.css` code of main page:

```css
html {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
 display: block;
}

audio, canvas, progress, video {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

audio:not([controls]) {
 display: none;
 height: 0;
}

[hidden], template {
 display: none;
}

a {
 background-color: transparent;
}

a:active, a:hover {
 outline: 0;
}

abbr[title] {
 border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

b, strong {
 font-weight: bold;
}

dfn {
 font-style: italic;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
 margin: 0.67em 0;
}

mark {
 background: #ff0;
 color: #000;
}

small {
 font-size: 80%;
}

sub, sup {
 font-size: 75%;
 line-height: 0;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

sup {
 top: -0.5em;
}

sub {
 bottom: -0.25em;
}

img {
 border: 0;
}

svg:not(:root) {
 overflow: hidden;
}

figure {
 padding: 1em;
}

hr {
 box-sizing: content-box;
 height: 0;
}

pre {
 overflow: auto;
}

code, kbd, pre, samp {
 font-family: monospace, monospace;
 font-size: 1em;
}

button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
 color: inherit;
 font: inherit;
 margin: 0;
}

button {
 overflow: visible;
}

button, select {
 text-transform: none;
}

button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
 -webkit-appearance: button;
 cursor: pointer;
}

button[disabled], html input[disabled] {
 cursor: default;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner, input::-moz-focus-inner {
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

input {
 line-height: normal;
}

input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
 height: auto;
}

input[type="search"] {
 -webkit-appearance: textfield;
 box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button, input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
}

fieldset {
 border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
 margin: 0 2px;
 padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

legend {
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

textarea {
 overflow: auto;
}

optgroup {
 font-weight: bold;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

td, th {
 padding: 0;
}



/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Elements
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

html {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
 /* Inherit box-sizing to make it easier to change the property for components that leverage other behavior; see http://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/ */
 box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
 background: #fff;
 /* Fallback for when there is no custom background color defined. */
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
 content: "";
}

blockquote, q {
 quotes: "" "";
}

hr {
 border: 0;
 height: 1px;
 margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

ul, ol {
 margin: 0 0 1.5em 3em;
}

ul {
 list-style: disc;
}

ol {
 list-style: decimal;
}

li > ul, li > ol {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-left: 1.5em;
}

dt {
 font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
 margin: 0 1.5em 1.5em;
}

img {
 height: auto;
 /* Make sure images are scaled correctly. */
 max-width: 100%;
 /* Adhere to container width. */
}

table {
 margin: 0 0 1.5em;
 width: 100%;
}



/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Navigation
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Links
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

a, a:visited {
 color: #02558E;
 font-weight: 600;
 cursor: pointer;
}

a:active {
 color: #09005e;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
 color: #5234f9;
}

a:focus {
 outline: thin dotted;
}

a:hover, a:active {
 outline: 0;
}

a, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
## Menus
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

.main-navigation {
 clear: both;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px 0;
}

.main-navigation ul {
 display: none;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
}

.main-navigation li {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}

.main-navigation a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navigation ul ul {
 box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 1.5em;
 left: -999em;
 z-index: 99999;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
 left: -999em;
 top: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul a {
 width: 200px;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li {
 width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation li:hover > a, .main-navigation li.focus > a {
}

.main-navigation ul ul:hover > a, .main-navigation ul ul .focus > a {
}

.main-navigation ul ul a:hover, .main-navigation ul ul a.focus {
}

.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul, .main-navigation ul li.focus > ul {
 left: auto;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul, .main-navigation ul ul li.focus > ul {
 left: 100%;
}

.main-navigation .current_page_item > a, .main-navigation .current-menu-item > a, .main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a, .main-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a {
}

/* Small menu. */

.menu-toggle, .main-navigation.toggled ul {
 display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
 .menu-toggle {
  display: none;
 }

 .main-navigation ul {
  display: block;
 }
}

.site-main .comment-navigation, .site-main .posts-navigation, .site-main .post-navigation {
 margin: 0 0 1.5em;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.comment-navigation .nav-previous, .posts-navigation .nav-previous, .post-navigation .nav-previous {
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
}

.comment-navigation .nav-next, .posts-navigation .nav-next, .post-navigation .nav-next {
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
 width: 50%;
}

.site-title {
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 52px;
 color: #666;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 font-weight: 300;
}

.site-title:hover,
.site-title:focus {
 color: #333;
}

#site-navigation .module.left {
 padding-left: 15px;
}

#site-navigation .container > .flex-row {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
}



/*!---------- 4. COLOURS ----------*/

.bg-primary {
 background: #02558E !important;
}

.bg-secondary {
 background: #f5f5f5;
}

.bg-dark {
 background: #0e1015;
}



/*!---------- 7. NAVIGATION ----------*/

.nav-container {
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 max-width: 100%;
}

nav {
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 max-width: 100%;

}

nav ul {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.module {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 32px;
}

.module-group {
 display: inline-block;
}

.module.left {
 float: left;
}

.module.right, .module-group.right {
 float: right;
}

nav .btn, .nav-bar .btn {
 margin: 0;
 height: auto;
}

.nav-bar {
 line-height: 53px;
}

nav {
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 background-color: rgba(2,85,142,1);
}

.nav-bar .module:not( .site-title-container ),
.nav-bar .module-group {
 height: 55px;
}

.nav-bar a:not( .custom-logo-link ) {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 55px;
}

.menu > li.dropdown {
 padding-right: 18px;
}

.dropdown:after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 font-size: 11px;
 content: "\f107";
 font-family: 'fontawesome';
 speak: none;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 text-transform: none;
}

.shapely-dropdown {
 display: none;
}

.main-navigation .menu {
 width: 100%;
 height: 55px;
}

.main-navigation .menu li a {
 font-size: 13px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 500;
 letter-spacing: -1px;
 color: #4c4c4c;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 max-width: 100%;
 white-space: normal;
}

.main-navigation .menu li a:hover,
.main-navigation .menu li a:focus,
.main-navigation .menu li:hover > a,
.main-navigation .menu li:focus > a,
.main-navigation .menu > li:hover:after,
.main-navigation .menu > li:focus:after {
 color: #5234f9;
}

.main-navigation .menu > li {
 margin-right: 32px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 opacity: 1;
 color: #4c4c4c;
}

.main-navigation .menu > li:last-child {
 margin-right: 0;
}

.main-navigation .menu > li ul {
 left: 0;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 0;
 background: #0e1015;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 99;
 top: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 10px, 0);
 visibility: hidden;
 margin-top: -1px;
}

.main-navigation .menu > li > ul > li {
 position: relative;
 line-height: 24px;
 width: 100%;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.main-navigation .menu > li > ul .dropdown:after {
 color: #0e1015;
 top: 1px;
 right: 24px;
 content: "\f105";
}

.main-navigation .menu > li > ul li a {
 color: #fff;
 height: auto;
 padding: 6px 24px;
}

.main-navigation .menu > li > ul > li ul {
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
}

.main-navigation .menu > li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation .menu > li:focus-within > ul {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
 visibility: visible;
}

.main-navigation .menu > li > ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation .menu > li > ul li:focus-within > ul {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
 visibility: visible;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
 .dropdown:after {
  display: none;
 }

 .shapely-dropdown {
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
 }

 .main-navigation .menu > li > ul li:hover > a,
 .main-navigation .menu > li > ul li:focus > a {
  background-color: transparent !important;
 }

 .main-navigation .menu li:hover > a,
 .main-navigation .menu li:focus > a {
  color: #4c4c4c;
 }

 body .main-navigation .menu > li > ul li:hover > a,
 body .main-navigation .menu > li > ul li:focus > a {
  color: #8c979e;
 }


}

@media all and (min-width: 991px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
 .dropdown-menu .shapely-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
 }

 .dropdown-menu .shapely-dropdown > .fa-angle-down:before {
  content: "\f105";
 }
}

@media all and (max-width: 991px) {
 .shapely-dropdown {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid;
 }

 .menu li a {
  padding: 10px 0;
 }

 #site-navigation.main-navigation .menu > li > ul li a {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
 }
}

.nav-container {
 min-height: 56px;
}

nav.outOfSight {
 transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -100px, 0);
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

nav.scrolled {
 transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

nav.fixed.scrolled {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

nav.fixed {
 top: 0;
 z-index: 999;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

nav.fixed {
 position: fixed;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
}

nav.fixed.scrolled {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu {
 border-radius: 0;
}

.nav-open {
 max-height: 10000px !important;
 height: auto !important;
}

.nav-open .navbar-collapse, .nav-open #menu {
 display: block;
}

.module.widget-handle {
 padding: 0 5px;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 margin: 0;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1100px) {
 .module.widget-handle {
  padding: 0 16px;
 }
}

@media all and (max-width: 991px) {

 .menu li:focus-within ul.dropdown-menu,
 ul.dropdown-menu.active {
  display: block !important;
 }
}

.module.widget-handle i {
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 53px;
 opacity: 1;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 color: #3a52bf;
}

.module.widget-handle:hover i,
.module.widget-handle:focus i {
 opacity: 1;
}

.widget-handle .function {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 cursor: default;
 width: 200px;
 background: #0e1015;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 99;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transform: translate3d(0, -200%, 0);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -200%, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -200%, 0);
 margin-top: -2px;
 right: 0;
}

.module.widget-handle:hover .function,
.module.widget-handle:focus .function,
.module.widget-handle .function.active {
 opacity: 1;
 transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
 visibility: visible;
}

.module.widget-handle .title {
 font-family: inherit;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: 600;
 display: none;
 opacity: .5;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.module.widget-handle .title:hover,
.module.widget-handle .title:focus {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html lang="lt-LT" style="scroll-behavior: auto;"><head>
 <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"> 
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
 <link rel="pingback" href="https://bsd.com/xmlrpc.php">

 <title></title>
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//s.w.org">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="b s d » Įrašų RSS srautas" href="https://bsd.com/lt/feed">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="b s d » Komentarų RSS srautas" href="https://bsd.com/lt/comments/feed">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/12.0.0-1\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/12.0.0-1\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"https:\/\/bsd.com\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.3.2"}};
   !function(e,a,t){var r,n,o,i,p=a.createElement("canvas"),s=p.getContext&&p.getContext("2d");function c(e,t){var a=String.fromCharCode;s.clearRect(0,0,p.width,p.height),s.fillText(a.apply(this,e),0,0);var r=p.toDataURL();return s.clearRect(0,0,p.width,p.height),s.fillText(a.apply(this,t),0,0),r===p.toDataURL()}function l(e){if(!s||!s.fillText)return!1;switch(s.textBaseline="top",s.font="600 32px Arial",e){case"flag":return!c([127987,65039,8205,9895,65039],[127987,65039,8203,9895,65039])&&(!c([55356,56826,55356,56819],[55356,56826,8203,55356,56819])&&!c([55356,57332,56128,56423,56128,56418,56128,56421,56128,56430,56128,56423,56128,56447],[55356,57332,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56418,8203,56128,56421,8203,56128,56430,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56447]));case"emoji":return!c([55357,56424,55356,57342,8205,55358,56605,8205,55357,56424,55356,57340],[55357,56424,55356,57342,8203,55358,56605,8203,55357,56424,55356,57340])}return!1}function d(e){var t=a.createElement("script");t.src=e,t.defer=t.type="text/javascript",a.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t)}for(i=Array("flag","emoji"),t.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},o=0;o<i.length;o++)t.supports[i[o]]=l(i[o]),t.supports.everything=t.supports.everything&&t.supports[i[o]],"flag"!==i[o]&&(t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&t.supports[i[o]]);t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!t.supports.flag,t.DOMReady=!1,t.readyCallback=function(){t.DOMReady=!0},t.supports.everything||(n=function(){t.readyCallback()},a.addEventListener?(a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",n,!1),e.addEventListener("load",n,!1)):(e.attachEvent("onload",n),a.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===a.readyState&&t.readyCallback()})),(r=t.source||{}).concatemoji?d(r.concatemoji):r.wpemoji&&r.twemoji&&(d(r.twemoji),d(r.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
  </script><script src="https://bsd.com/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.3.2" type="text/javascript" defer=""></script>
  <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
 display: inline !important;
 border: none !important;
 box-shadow: none !important;
 height: 1em !important;
 width: 1em !important;
 margin: 0 .07em !important;
 vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
 background: none !important;
 padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" id="dashicons-css" href="https://bsd.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=5.3.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="admin-bar-css" href="https://bsd.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=5.3.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="wp-block-library-css" href="https://bsd.com/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.3.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="widgetopts-styles-css" href="https://bsd.com/wp-content/plugins/widget-options/assets/css/widget-options.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css" href="https://bsd.com/wp-content/themes/shapely/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=5.3.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="font-awesome-css" href="https://bsd.com/wp-content/themes/shapely/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=5.3.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="shapely-fonts-css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway%3A100%2C300%2C400%2C500%2C600%2C700&amp;ver=5.3.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="flexslider-css" href="https://bsd.com/wp-content/themes/shapely/assets/css/flexslider.css?ver=5.3.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="shapely-style-css" href="https://bsd.com/wp-content/themes/shapely/style.css?ver=5.3.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="owl.carousel-css" href="https://bsd.com/wp-content/themes/shapely/assets/js/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.css?ver=5.3.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="owl.carousel.theme-css" href="https://bsd.com/wp-content/themes/shapely/assets/js/owl-carousel/owl.theme.default.css?ver=5.3.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="litespeed-cache-css" href="https://bsd.com/wp-content/plugins/litespeed-cache/css/litespeed.css?ver=2.9.9.2" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bsd.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bsd.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1"></script>
<link rel="https://api.w.org/" href="https://bsd.com/wp-json/">
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="https://bsd.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd">
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="https://bsd.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml"> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 5.3.2">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://bsd.com/lt/">
<link rel="shortlink" href="https://bsd.com/">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="https://bsd.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbsd.com%2Flt%2F">
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="https://bsd.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbsd.com%2Flt%2F&amp;format=xml">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://bsd.com/lt/" hreflang="lt">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://bsd.com/" hreflang="en">
<style type="text/css"></style><style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
 html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
 * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
 @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
  html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
  * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
 }
</style>
 <link rel="icon" href="https://bsd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/cropped-a115a8f5-0ccc-40c1-b068-afd6874e3580_200x200-1-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" href="https://bsd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/cropped-a115a8f5-0ccc-40c1-b068-afd6874e3580_200x200-1-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="https://bsd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/cropped-a115a8f5-0ccc-40c1-b068-afd6874e3580_200x200-1-180x180.png">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://bsd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/cropped-a115a8f5-0ccc-40c1-b068-afd6874e3580_200x200-1-270x270.png">

  </head>

<body class="home page-template page-template-page-templates page-template-template-home page-template-page-templatestemplate-home-php page page-id-12 logged-in admin-bar has-sidebar-right customize-support"><div class="parallax-mirror" style="visibility: visible; z-index: -100; position: fixed; top: 109px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); height: 754px; width: 1030px;"><img class="parallax-slider" src="https://bsd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/4B142012-915D-4729-BE31-181EA238B0E9.jpeg" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); position: absolute; top: -87.2px; left: -50px; height: 754px; width: 1131px; max-width: none;"></div>
<div id="page" class="site">
 <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">Skip to content</a>

 <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
  <div class="nav-container">
   <nav style="background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);" id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="container nav-bar nav-open">
     <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="module left site-title-container">
       <a href="https://bsd.com/lt/" class="custom-logo-link"><span class="site-title">b s d</span></a>      </div>
      <button class="module widget-handle mobile-toggle right visible-sm visible-xs active toggle-search">
       <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="module-group right">
       <div class="module left">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"><ul id="menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-71"><a title="Apie mus" href="https://bsd.com/apie-mus#text-3" data-ps2id-api="true">Apie mus</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-104"><a title="Paslaugos" href="https://bsd.com/lt/paslaugos" data-ps2id-api="true">Paslaugos</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-241" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-241"><a title="Naujienos" href="https://bsd.com/naujienos/covid-19-pagalba" data-ps2id-api="true">Naujienos</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65"><a title="Kontaktai" href="https://bsd.com/lt/kontaktai" data-ps2id-api="true">Kontaktai</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-66" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-66"><a title="Susisiekti" href="https://bsd.com/susisiekti#wpforms-widget-2" data-ps2id-api="true">Susisiekti</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-259" class="pll-parent-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-259 dropdown"><a title="Lietuviškai" href="#pll_switcher" data-ps2id-api="true">Lietuviškai </a><span class="dropdown-toggle shapely-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
 <li class="lang-item lang-item-27 lang-item-lt current-lang lang-item-first menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-259-lt"><a title="Lietuviškai" href="https://bsd.com/lt/" data-ps2id-api="true" hreflang="lt-LT" lang="lt-LT">Lietuviškai</a></li>
 <li class="lang-item lang-item-30 lang-item-en menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-259-en"><a title="English" href="https://bsd.com/" data-ps2id-api="true" hreflang="en-US" lang="en-US">English</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>       </div>
       <!--end of menu module-->

      </div>
      <!--end of module group-->
     </div>
    </div>
   </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
  </div>
 </header><!-- #masthead -->



</div><!-- #page -->





<!-- Page generated by LiteSpeed Cache 2.9.9.2 on 2020-04-14 19:51:57 --></body></html>
```

I tried suggestions such as include on very top of the page this line (but didn't helped):

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

**EDIT:**
Here on stackoverflow works only on click. The last item is in question:

```
id="menu-item-259"
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem using your code, after running your code, the output [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKhNG.png), try to use F12 developer tools to check, it seems that I can't access the links from "https://bsd.com". So, I suggest you could try to change the link reference or post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is easier for us to help you solve the problem.

Comment: I produced behaviour, please note that page URL is obfuscated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the following CSS style at the end of the .css file:

```
    .main-navigation .menu > li:hover > ul {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
        -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0px, 0);
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .main-navigation .menu > li > ul li:hover > a {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

The result in IE 11 browser and Edge browser (Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0) as below  ([sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/bgoy596t/)):

[image]

Comment: On IE works perfectly, on Edge it works on first main page, but if I navigate to other page or return back to main page it breaks (do not appear). I think I should put it not in the end?

Comment: Ok I cleared Edge cache and it is working I suppose, but how can I remove the #pll_switcher in Url that appears when I click on area English

Comment: Congratulation. About removing the #pll_switcher in Url, since it is a hyperlink (<a> tag),  I think you have to use JavaScript to capture the hyperlink click event, in the click event, prevent the hyperlink default event using [the Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method. After that, redirect to a new page using window.location.href property, more detail information. please check [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp).

Comment: Besides, since the original question is solved, I suggest you could mark this reply as an accepted answer for this question when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kind of issues. And, if you have any further question, I suggest you could post a new question, it is better for us to find your question and help you solve it. Thanks for your understanding. ^_^